# Stopping a javascript function from running when another function is?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The code below is a complete drawing application, however the function for the brush and square only work once. After you use the brush and try to change to square, they both run at the same time so instead of drawing just a square a circle is drawn at the same time too. How do i stop this function ?? I have marked where the code for the brush and square starts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drawing</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
    #toolbar{
        width:983px;
        height:50px;
        padding:10px;
        background:#2f2f2f;
        margin-bottom:1px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color:#ffffff;
            user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;

    }
    .sizecontrol{
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        background: #4f4f4f;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;

    }
    #size{
        float:left;
    }
    #colors{
        float:right;
    }
    .swatch{
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius:15px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        background-color:cyan;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .swatch.active{
        border:#fff solid 3px;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .tools{
        float:left;
        height:30px;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: #434343;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left:5px;

    }
    .tools:hover{
        background:#818181;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body style="background:#999;" >


    <div id="content">
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="size">
                Size <span id="sizeval">10</span>

                <div id="decsize" class="sizecontrol">-</div><!-- Close decsize -->
                <div id="incsize" class="sizecontrol">+</div><!-- Close incsize -->
            </div><!-- Close div size -->
            <div id="colors">
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#FF0000"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#00FF00"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#0000FF;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#FFFF00;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#00FFFF;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#FF00FF;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#FF8000;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#848484;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#000;"></div>
                <div class="swatch" style="background-color:#FFF;"></div>
            </div><!-- close colors div -->
            <div id="save" class="tools">Save</div><!-- close save div -->
            <div id="clear" class="tools">Clear</div><!-- close clear div -->
            <div id="square" class="tools" >Square</div><!-- close square div -->
            <div id="brush" class="tools">brush</div><!-- close square div -->
        </div><!-- close div tool bar --> 
        <canvas id="canvas" style="background:#FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000;">
            Sorry Your Browser is not upto date enough for this app. Plese update your browser
        </canvas>


        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">




            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var size = 10;
            var dragging = false;
            var squareEngage = false;
            var brushEngage = false;

            canvas.width = 1000;
            canvas.height = 550;
            context.lineWidth = size*2;





            var setSize = function(newSize){

                function isInt(n) {
                    return n % 1 === 0;
                }
                if(isInt(newSize) == false){
                    newSize = newSize - 0.5;
                }else if(newSize <= 5){
                    interval = 1;
                }else if(newSize <= 22){
                    interval = 2;
                }else if(newSize > 20){
                    interval = 5;
                }
                if(newSize == 22){
                    newSize = 25;
                }

                if(newSize<minSize){
                    newSize = minSize;
                }else if(newSize>maxSize){
                    newSize = maxSize;
                }
                size = newSize;
                context.lineWidth = size*2;

                SizeSpan.innerHTML=size;
            }

            var minSize = 0.5;
            var maxSize = 100;
            var defaultSize = 20;
            var interval = 5;
            var SizeSpan = document.getElementById('sizeval');
            var decSize = document.getElementById('decsize');
            var incSize = document.getElementById('incsize');
            var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
            var square = document.getElementById('square');
            var brush = document.getElementById('brush');   



/////////////////////////// Function for the square to draw \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                square.addEventListener('click', function(){

                squareEngage = true;

                brush.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    squareEngage = false;

                });


            if(squareEngage == true){
                var putPoint2 = function(e){
                    if(dragging2){


                        context.fillRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY,size,size);

                    }
                }

                var engage2 = function(e){
                    dragging2 = true;
                    putPoint2(e);
                }
                var disengage2 = function(){
                    dragging2 = false;
                    context.beginPath();
                }

                    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage2);
                    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint2); //Looks for when the mouse is pressed down
                    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage2);
                }


            });

/////////////////////////// Function for the brush to draw \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            brush.addEventListener('click', function(){

                square.addEventListener('click', function(){

                    brushEngage = false;
                });
                brushEngage = true;

            if(brushEngage == true){
                var putPoint = function(e){
                if(dragging){
                context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                context.stroke();
                context.beginPath(); //This starts the path drawing
                context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, size, 0, Math.PI*2); //This is the paointer cirlce that will be drawn 
                context.fill();
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);

                }
            }

            var engage = function(e){
                dragging = true;
                putPoint(e);

            }
            var disengage = function(){
                dragging = false;
                context.beginPath();
            }

                canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint); //Looks for when the mouse is pressed down
                canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);
            }


            });

            decSize.addEventListener('click', function(){
                setSize(size-interval);


            });
            clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
                canvas.width = 1000;
                canvas.height = 550;
                context.lineWidth = size*2;
            });
            incSize.addEventListener('click', function(){
                setSize(size+interval);
            });
            setSize(defaultSize);


            var swatches = document.getElementsByClassName('swatch');
                for(var i=0, n=swatches.length;i<n;i++){
                    swatches[i].addEventListener('click', setSwatch);

                }

            for(var i=0,n=colors.length;i<n;i++){
                var swatch = document.createElement('div');
                swatch.className = 'swatch';

            }

                function setColor(color){
                        context.fillStyle = color;
                        context.strokeStyle = color;
                        var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
                        if(active){
                            active.className = 'swatch';
                        }
                }
            function setSwatch(e){
                    //Identifiy swatch
                    var swatch = e.target;
                    setColor(swatch.style.backgroundColor);
                    swatch.className += ' active';
                }
            setSwatch({target: document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]});




        </script>
    </div><!-- Close content -->



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `addEventListener()` really adds new listeners, it doesn't override the existing listeners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick-fixed JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var size = 10;
    var dragging = false;
    var dragging2 = false; // Added missing declaration
    var engaged; // Added declaration for rescoped function
    var engaged2; // Added declaration for rescoped function
    // Removed extra variables
    canvas.width = 1000;
    canvas.height = 550;
    context.lineWidth = size * 2;
    var setSize = function (newSize) {
        function isInt(n) {
            return n % 1 === 0;
        }
        if (isInt(newSize) == false) {
            newSize = newSize - 0.5;
        } else if (newSize <= 5) {
            interval = 1;
        } else if (newSize <= 22) {
            interval = 2;
        } else if (newSize > 20) {
            interval = 5;
        }
        if (newSize == 22) {
            newSize = 25;
        }
        if (newSize < minSize) {
            newSize = minSize;
        } else if (newSize > maxSize) {
            newSize = maxSize;
        }
        size = newSize;
        context.lineWidth = size * 2;
        SizeSpan.innerHTML = size;
    }
    var minSize = 0.5;
    var maxSize = 100;
    var defaultSize = 20;
    var interval = 5;
    var SizeSpan = document.getElementById('sizeval');
    var decSize = document.getElementById('decsize');
    var incSize = document.getElementById('incsize');
    var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
    var square = document.getElementById('square');
    var brush = document.getElementById('brush');
     // Function for the square to draw
    square.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Removed extra code
        var putPoint2 = function (e) {
            if (dragging2) {
                context.fillRect(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, size, size);
            }
        };
        engage2 = function (e) { // Made engage2() "global" to refer it in engage()
            dragging2 = true;
            putPoint2(e);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint2); // Repositioned event attachment
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage2); // Repositioned event attachment
        };
        var disengage2 = function () {
            dragging2 = false;
            context.beginPath();
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', putPoint2); // Added event detachment
            canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', disengage2); // Added event detachment
        };
        if (typeof engage === 'function') { // Added event detachment
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', engage);
        }
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage2);
    });         
    // Function for the brush to draw
    brush.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Removed extra code
        var putPoint = function (e) {
                if (dragging) {
                    context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                    context.stroke();
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.arc(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    context.fill();
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                }
            };
            engage = function (e) { // Made engage() "global" to refer it in engage2()
                dragging = true;
                putPoint(e);
                canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint); // Repositioned event attachment
                canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage); // Repositioned event attachment
            };
            var disengage = function () {
                dragging = false;
                context.beginPath();
                canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', putPoint); // Added event detachment
                canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', disengage); // Added event detachment
            };
            if (typeof engage2 === 'function') { // Added event detachment
                canvas.removeEventListener('mousedown', engage2);
            }
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);               
    });
    decSize.addEventListener('click', function () {
        setSize(size - interval);
    });         
    clear.addEventListener('click', function () {
        canvas.width = 1000;
        canvas.height = 550;
        context.lineWidth = size * 2;
    });         
    incSize.addEventListener('click', function () {
        setSize(size + interval);
    });         
    setSize(defaultSize);
    var swatches = document.getElementsByClassName('swatch');
    for (var i = 0, n = swatches.length; i < n; i++) {
        swatches[i].addEventListener('click', setSwatch);
    }
    for (var i = 0, n = colors.length; i < n; i++) {
        var swatch = document.createElement('div');
        swatch.className = 'swatch';
    }
    function setColor(color) {
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        var active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0];
        if (active) {
            active.className = 'swatch';
        }
    }
    function setSwatch(e) {
        var swatch = e.target;
        if (swatch) { // Added existense check for swatch
            setColor(swatch.style.backgroundColor);
            swatch.className += ' active';
        }
    }           
    setSwatch({
        target: document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0]
    });
};
```

As you can see, I've wrapped the whole script within `window.onload` to avoid global variables. Changes are commented on the lines they occur.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5ADE/). Also looks like this code is not working in FF, though in Chrome and IE11 it works fine. There are no errors when running with FF, but nothing is drawn.

Comment: Thank you this has worked now life saver :D and i know its not working in Firefox i think this is because it does not support the canvas element. Is it possible for you to explain why wrapping it in window.load worked??? please

Comment: `window.onload` doesn't fix anything, it just creates a namespace, so you can avoid to pollute global namespace. There are a lot of other changes in the code, which make it work. The code itself would work without `window.onload` too. Definitely FF supports `canvas`, it has to be something else...

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest your event listeners. change

```
         brush.addEventListener('click', function(){

            square.addEventListener('click', function(){

                brushEngage = false;
            });
            brushEngage = true;

            ...
```

to

```
        brush.addEventListener('click', function(){

            squareEngage = false;
            brushEngage = true;

            ...
```

or

```
        square.addEventListener('click', function(){

            brushEngage = false;
        });

        brush.addEventListener('click', function(){

            brushEngage = true;

            ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried these already and they have failed to work i think because the function may already be running